# Biblatex punctuation recognition

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, punctuation, delimiters

I'm trying to switch to biblatex/biber. I started using the authortitle style for the bibliography. For my thesis I need lots of changes in the style. 
Along the way I changed the separator between entry fields in the bibliography to be a comma and not a dot. For that I used the following command:

```
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
```

Later when I added an article with a question mark in it's title, I realised that my redefinition of `\newunitpunct` must've destroyed some automated punctuation recognitions. Or at least, that's what I think the problem is. Because when I remove the redefinition I end up with dots as separators but the "punctuation recognition" works.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Thanks!

P.S. I've included a working sample.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,%
citestyle=authortitle-comp,%
bibstyle=authortitle,%
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 
\renewbibmacro{in:}{% kein 'in' bei @article
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
%
 \makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{{#1%\isdot
}}
\makeatother
% 
%
% ==== This is the problem, I think...When I delete this line it works.
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

% === BIB
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
    author  ={Test Author},
    title   ={Interesting Title?},
    journal ={Journal},
    year    ={2018},
}
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{document}
% ===
\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
    This is an example.\footcite{test}\\
I wanted the separator between entry fields to be a comma not a dot. Thats why I changed it to \verb|\addcomma|.\\ But it seems like \verb|\newunitpunct| was configured to \enquote{know} if there were punctuations in the title. Now because of my changes it \verb|\newunitpunct| doesn't recognise those punctuations anymore. Thus I end up with \enquote{\textbf{?,}}
instead of \enquote{\textbf{?}}.\\  
    How can I make it work?
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the intended behaviour. `biblatex` tries to avoid a full stop/period running in with other punctuation marks, but a question mark and comma are considered OK.

Comment: @moewe Understood. Any ideas how I can configure that "punctuation recognition" for commas as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\DeclarePunctuationPairs` is the command you are looking for. That command is language-specific and must therefore live in `\DefineBibliographyExtras`.

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*}}
```

This set-up always swallows the comma after all punctuation except an abbreviation dot.

---

The command is documented in §4.7.5 *Configuring Punctuation and Capitalization* on pp. 246-247 of the `biblatex` manual

The syntax is `\DeclarePunctuationPairs{<identifier>}{<characters>}`

The command declares the punctuation marks that `<identifier>` can follow without being dropped.

> The `<identifier>` selects the command to be configured. The identifiers correspond to the names of the punctuation commands from §4.7.3 without the `\add` prefix, i.e., valid `<identifier>` strings are `dot`, `comma`, `semicolon`, `colon`, `period`, `exclam`, `question`. The `<characters>` argument is an undelimited list of punctuation marks.
>   Valid `<characters>` are comma, semicolon, colon, period, exclamation mark, question mark, and asterisk. A period in the `<characters>` argument denotes an end-of-sentence period, an asterisk the dot after an abbreviation.

The default value

```
\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*!?}
```

for the comma allows the combinations "!,", "?," and ".," (if the dot signifies an abbreviation). You don't want the "?," and "!,", so you want the setting

```
\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*}
```

Comment: Your additional explanation helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: What about ")"? How can I tell biblatex to put a comma after a closing bracket?

Comment: @rsa-krypto Normally commas after closing brackets should not be swallowed, so I don't think `\DeclarePunctuationPairs` would help here. I'm not quite sure what you are after, though. Would it be possible to ask a new question with MWE that shows the use case that you have in mind?