# In BibLaTeX, how to delimit title and subtitle by a colon, but not when title ends with question mark?

Tags: biblatex

With BibLaTeX, I'd like to separate title and subtitle with a colon, as is done in some citation styles. However, I'd like the mechanism to detect if the the title ends in a quotation mark and if it does, omit the `subtitlepunct`.

The documentation in §4.7.3 says:

> `\addcolon` Adds a colon unless it is preceded by a comma, a
> semicolon, another colon, or a period.

Can I add "quotation mark" to that list? I.e., is there a solution that avoids `\isdot`?

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @book{testbook,
      author = {A. U. Thor},
      year = {2020},
      title = {An example title?},
      subtitle = {An example subtitle}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{testbook}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare acceptable punctuation before `\addcolon` with `\DeclarePunctuationPairs`. The default setting

```
\DeclarePunctuationPairs{colon}{*!?}
```

allows abbreviation dots, exclamation marks and question marks before a colon. After all other punctuation marks the colon is suppressed.

You probably want

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclarePunctuationPairs{colon}{*}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{testbook,
  author   = {A. U. Thor},
  year     = {2020},
  title    = {An example title?},
  subtitle = {An example subtitle}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{testbook}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: A. U. Thor. An example title? An example subtitle. 2020.]

**Note** that `\DeclarePunctuationPairs` is usually language-specific and therefore usually needs to live in `\DefineBibliographyExtras`. This is not required in the MWE (which loads neither `babel` nor `polyglossia`), but may be very relevant in your real-world application. See [Biblatex punctuation recognition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428478/35864) for more details.